# quadratic function application

Tags: calculus, quadratics, applications

[image]

I was wondering if this the the correct way to answer the question in the image:

$A=(x)=-x^2+1500x=-1(x^2-1500x)=-1x^2-1500x+(750)^2-(750)^2)$
$A=(x)=-(x^2-1500x+(750)^2)+(750)^2=-(x-750)^2+(750)^2$

Which would mean the vertex is $(750,750^2)$ making the maximum area $562,000m^2$

Comment: That's likely just a typo, but $750^2=562,\color{red}{500}\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having shown the answer for part (i), you now have an expression for A. 
You have completed the square to obtain an expression which gives you the minimum of your quadratic, and this is fine, and is correct. However I believe from the wording of the question (*calculus*) that the intended method was to differentiate. This is an answer for part (ii).

$$\frac{dA}{dx}=1500-2x\\\frac{dA}{dx}=0\implies x=750\implies A=1500\cdot750-750^2=2\cdot750\cdot750-750\cdot750=750^2$$ just as you got.

---

As for part (i), you need to show that the area is $A=1500x-x^2$. You can write the perimeter in terms of $x$ and $y$, and you can also write the area in terms of  $x$ and $y$. Simply substituting one equation into the other will give an expression for the area in terms of $x$, and it should match the answer given. This is what the 6 marks are awarded for.

Then what I have done above for part (ii) will yield the other marks.

Comment: Ahh yes thanks, also one more thing am I suppose to do something with the $A=1500x-x^2$ which is i) part of the question?

Comment: @Shmekel Yes, that is what I differentiated to obtain $\frac{dA}{dx}$!

Comment: Alright but i) is worth 6 marks and ii) 8 so calculating $dA/dx$ covers both of those question right? Or am I missing something or is the question mark layout just weird?

Comment: @Shmekel edited to add this in - the differentiation is only mentioned in part (ii), so of course this is where the marks are awarded. I had previously assumed you were only asking about part (ii) of the question, so didn't talk about part (i), but I have added this in without fully solving it - from what I wrote, do you think you can do part (i) by yourself?

Comment: $2y+2y=3000$ -> $2y=3000-2x = y=1500x-x$ -> $A=xy=x(1500-x)=1500x-x^2$ Something like this?

Comment: @Shmekel yes, perfect :)

Comment: All right thanks a lot!